# how do i send a jpeg file over an SSH channel

Tags: ssh

I have managed to read a text file over an `SSH` channel using an `Ubuntu` `Linux` to serve as an `SSH` server. My question is how do i send an image file over and display it in an application like a `JPanel`? I seem to have problems doing that.

Below is the code that I have used which is from this forum. Credits to user World

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
{

    String user="larry";
    String password="123";
    String host="192.168.174.131";
    int port = 22;
    String remoteFile="/home/larry/seohyun.jpg";



    try
    {
        JSch jsch=new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user,host,port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
        System.out.println("Establishing connection");
        session.connect();

        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        System.out.println("Creating SFTP Channel.");
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel=(ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        System.out.println("SFTP Channel Established");

        InputStream out=null;
        out=sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));

        String imageName = br.readLine();
        File input = new File(imageName);
        image = ImageIO.read(input);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Image");
        Panel panel = new TestSSH();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);




    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.print(e);
    }

}
```

However I can`t seem to be able to display the image on the`JPanel`.

it gives me the following exception

```
Establishing connection
Connection Established
Creating SFTP Channel.
SFTP Channel Established
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

however, i have checked the file path countless times. It is correct.
May i know what`s wrong with my code?